# How can I show the relative commit references (e.g. HEAD~1, HEAD~2) instead of the SHA-1 hashes in a git log?

Tags: git

Sometimes it is more convenient to view these references rather than the full SHA-1 hash. This seemed to be the default behavior when displaying commits through `git show-branch`.

Is it possible to do this with `git log`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no: there's no formatting directive in `git log` to produce a relative name.  It's kind of tricky to calculate—it's much easier to go the other way, from relative name to hash—and `git log` doesn't try.

(Note that `HEAD~3` or whatever is only valid until you store a new hash ID in the current branch name or otherwise change HEAD.  But that's true of relative dates in `reflog` output as well, so that's no excuse for Git not trying. :-) )